# Error when running update.php about field_data_body existing

Tags: 7, updating

```
DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table field_data_body already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 660 of /srv/bindings/e27b77cd6512471f902f88e9e0704451/code/includes/database/schema.inc).
```

Any thoughts on where to track this down? Seems someone decided to delete all the field_body instances on the site and replace them with field_page_body, but I'm not sure why that would cause the above issue during an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to apply this patch, that can be maybe the solution for you :

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/1551132-drupal-install-schema-shared-tables-69-D7.patch

Comment: Hmm this worked on my local machine, but not Pantheon. Oh well...I'll give you an up-vote.

Comment: Oh no I see I'm getting a new error: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot add field file_managed.origname: field already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->addField() (line 328 of includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).
Since I'm getting a new error, I'll accept this answer, thanks.

Comment: Does that error appeared when you were trying to use update.php? can you clean the cache of your Drupal?

Comment: Yes it happens after clicking continue when running update.php. Clearing the cache did not have any affect.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any other solution to that new error